# max(count(*)) for multiple results

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables:

```
Clients(client_id(pk),client_name,phone,email)
orders(order_number(pk),date,client_id,method)
```

I want to select only the details of the clients with the most orders (ex:if the highest number of orders is 6 and there are 3 clients with that number of orders I want all 3 of them to be shown). My problem is that I can only display one client's details and I want to see all the max values's details.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT MAX(NUMBER_OF_ORDERS)
FROM (
    SELECT C.CLIENT_NAME,
           COUNT(O.CLIENT_ID) NUMBER_OF_ORDERS
    FROM CLIENTS C,
         ORDERS O
    WHERE C.ID_CLIENT = O.ID_CLIENT
    GROUP BY C.NUME_CLIENT
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to select only the details of the clients with the most orders

Starting Oracle 12, this is easy with the row-limit clause:

```
SELECT C.CLIENT_NAME, COUNT(O.CLIENT_ID) NUMBER_OF_ORDERS
FROM CLIENTS C
INNER JOIN ORDERS O ON C.ID_CLIENT = O.ID_CLIENT
GROUP BY C.NUME_CLIENT, C.CLIENT_NAME
ORDER BY NUMBER_OF_ORDERS DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES
```

In earlier versions, one option is to use window functions:

```
SELECT CLIENT_NAME, NUMBER_OF_ORDERS
FROM (
    SELECT 
        C.CLIENT_NAME, 
        COUNT(O.CLIENT_ID) NUMBER_OF_ORDERS, 
        RANK() OVER(ORDER BY COUNT(O.CLIENT_ID) DESC) RN
    FROM CLIENTS C
    INNER JOIN ORDERS O ON C.ID_CLIENT = O.ID_CLIENT
    GROUP BY C.NUME_CLIENT, C.CLIENT_NAME
) T
WHERE RN = 1
```

Important notes:

- *always* use explicit, standard joins (with the `ON` keyword) rather than old-school, implicit joins (with a comma in the `FROM` clause), whose syntax has fallen out of favor for decades
- all non-aggregated columns that appear in the `SELECT` clause must be listed in the `GROUP BY` clause; your original query is missing `C.CLIENT_NAME` in the `GROUP BY` clause. In Oracle and most other database, this is a syntax error

Comment: Thank you, works just great. So my other question is, could this have been done without the rank function?

Comment: @ANDU: the first query does not use `rank()`, as you can see.